# How to make a script to insert data in my default sqlite3 database django

Tags: python, django, database, sqlite

I have defined my model and all in Django and if a user is registering via my application the user is well register in the database. The problem is I have a file containing a JSON with plenty of users.
I want to do a job that allow me to read this file and insert all the user in my database.

What is the best way to do it? How to connect to the Database without using Django?

Comment: you can use module `sqlite3`, `sqlalchemy`, `peewee`. Or you can try to convert `JSON` into `CSV` and then import directly to database using some Database Viewer/Editor. I don'ty know if they can import data directly from `JSON` - ie. [DB Browser for SQLite](http://sqlitebrowser.org/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why do you want to connect to the database without Django? I would do it using Django, but you need to initialize Django, to be able to run scripts against it. Something like this should do it:

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append('/path/to/django/project')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'project_name.settings'
import django
django.setup()
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

for row in data:
    user = User.objects.create_user(username=row['username'])
```

`/path/to/django/project`  is the path to the folder where the directory containing your settings is. For example with hierarchy of:

```
/projects/my_project
/projects/my_project/my_app
/projects/my_project/my_project/setting.py
```

you you need to append `/projects/my_project`.

If instead of the Django `User` model you need to work with a custom model, instead of

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

do

```
from app_name.models import ModelName
```

Comment: It's just that I don't really know where to put that job so I have a folder:
project wich contains: django_project (Where my app and my settings are) and a folder job (Where I do all my jobs, crawler and stuff to aliment my database)

Comment: With the code above you explicitly initialize your Django environment in the script, so it doesn't matter where the script resides. You can put it in the jobs-folder if you like.

Comment: "/path/to/django/project" this path must end-up on my settings.py where I config my database?

Comment: No, it's one level below that. In other words, it's path to the directory where the folder containing your settings file is.

Comment: Ok thanks for the edit. I don't use the defined User class I defined my own one so I try to replace: from django.contrib.auth.models import User by from .models import Dater but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Try `from app_name.models import Dater`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to insert data without going through django's views, use the shell

Run `python manage.py shell` in your app's directory.

Then import JSON data through python's `json.loads()`and loop through the data creating and saving models.

You can also use `bulk_create` to create models.

```
YourCustomUserModel.objects.bulk_create([
    YourCustomUserModel(username=datarow.username)
    for datarow in data
])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Django's native `manage.py` command instead:

Inside of your `yourapp` directory, create the tree structure (including the folder `management`), like so:

```
yourapp
├── admin.py
├── __init__.py
├── management
│   ├── commands
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── populate_db.py
│   └── __init__.py
├── models.py
... other files
```

Then, inside the file `populate_db.py` write the appropriate code to populate your database, e.g.:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from yourapp.models import Post, Tag

class Command(BaseCommand):
    args = '<foo bar ...>'
    help = 'our help string comes here'

    def _create_tags(self):
        tlisp = Tag(name='Python')
        tlisp.save()

        tjava = Tag(name='Java')
        tjava.save()

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        self._create_tags()
```

With this setup you can run `$ python manage.py populate_db` to automatically populate your database.

And of course you can expand this code to read input from e.g. a JSON file that you can keep in a `data` folder of your app. This allows you to commit non-sensible data that should be part of your app to version control without having to compromise the database (and thereby potentially your superuser access).

---

Credit for this elegant solution goes to Eli Bendersky: https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2014/02/15/programmatically-populating-a-django-database