# Django - PostgreSQL doesn't match default attribute

Tags: django, postgresql

I have the following model at Django:

```
class Community(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='Membership')
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

But when I check the structure of the table (using Postico for PostgreSQL) the field of date_created after applying the migrations shows **no default**.

[image]

I have also tried with explicitly `default=date.today()` but it does not work.

Any ideas what I am missing?

Thanks,
Pablo

**EDIT**

Great thanks to this post: [How to make a script to insert data in my default sqlite3 database django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41518910/how-to-make-a-script-to-insert-data-in-my-default-sqlite3-database-django)

I was trying to populate the database via script using PostgreSQL driver, when it is way simpler importing the Django models a use the *create* method (also thanks to [Daniel Roseman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104349/daniel-roseman) in the comments that led me find the post).

Comment: The default attributes are typically *not* set in the database later, but in the Django layer, since you can attach anything function to it. For example functions that depend on the time, Django settings, etc.

Comment: What about if I am making a script to populate the table with random generated communities using psycopg2? It is demanding the date_created value

Comment: You should use Django's model classes to write your script, rather than direct db access.