# django.setup() not finding my Django Project

Tags: python, django, faker, django-3.0

I am trying to write a faker script to populate my Django 3.0.4 project with some dummy data, but am getting stuck at the very beginning of the script.

If I run this:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'MyProject.settings')

import django
django.setup()
```

I get this error:

```
     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MyProject'
```

The script is in the same folder as my settings.py, urls.py, etc... and it's being executed within the venv for the django project.

Why can't if find my project when django.setup() is executed?

Answer (score 4):

Found the answer here: [How to make a script to insert data in my default sqlite3 database django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41518910/how-to-make-a-script-to-insert-data-in-my-default-sqlite3-database-django)

Had to append the project directory to sys.path and it was all good.  A little weird given the script was running in that dir but it worked.  Also modified the code to pull the scripts path rather than hard coding it like the above link.

Final code looks like this:

```
import os, sys
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
sys.path.append(BASE_DIR)
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'MyProject.settings')

import django
django.setup()
```

Answer (score 0):

My initial guess, since it is a moduleNotFoundError, is that you are using the display name of your project instead of the lib-name. Try switching to lowercase 'myproject.settings'.

Comment: tried that, same error.  Can't find the lower case module either.  Is there a way to look up the actual project name in the settings or other config file somewhere?

Comment: Actually no, the case is right.  In settings.py I can see it calling MyProject.urls and MyProject.wsgi.application, etc... and the site runs correctly, so that has me even more confused now.